# ReflectionOnlyGetType vs GetType

Tags: c#, .net

I understand from the api documentation that ReflectionOnlyGetType returns a type, much like GetType. The difference is that with ReflectionOnlyGetType, the type is loaded for reflection only, not for execution.

So why does this work:

```
    Type t = Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", false, false);
    ConstructorInfo[] cis = t.GetConstructors();
    foreach (ConstructorInfo ci in cis)
    {
        if (ci.GetParameters().Length == 0)
        {
            // ! no arg constructor found! let's call it!
            Object o = ci.Invoke(new Object[]{});
            Console.WriteLine("But wait, it was supposed to be reflection only??");
            Console.WriteLine(o.GetType().Name);
            List<String> lli = (List<String>)o;
            lli.Add("but how can this be?");
            Console.WriteLine(lli.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("I am doing a lot more than reflection here!");
        }
    }
```

My question is: I seem to be able to do more than reflect on the members of this type. Have I misunderstood "execution" when they say the type is loaded "for reflection only, not for execution"? Or is ReflectionOnlyGetType returning a different (non-reflection-only) type if the type was already "loaded" and here was loaded by virtue of being in mscorlib? Or is it something different entirely?

Comment: Of course `mscorlib` has already been loaded for execution by the runtime.

Comment: If you want something that will *guaranteed* to be reflection-only, IKVM.Reflection.dll can be handy; that is basically a completely separate loader / parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading a type from `mscorlib` which has already been loaded for execution by the runtime. You can check the `ReflectionOnly` property on an Assembly to see if it is loaded into a ReflectionOnly context. In your sample,

```
Type t = Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", false, false);
Console.WriteLine(t.Assembly.ReflectionOnly); // prints False.
```

It seems reflecting over mscorlib is somewhat restricted. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331.aspx):

> You cannot use the reflection-only context to load a version of
>   mscorlib.dll from a version of the .NET Framework other than the
>   version in the execution context.

I'm guessing that extends to loading the one in the current execution context into the reflection-only context.

It seems to work with other BCL assemblies:

```
Console.WriteLine(Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089").ReflectionOnly); // prints True
```

Comment: Almost got it.. does that mean when you invoke GetType or ReflectionOnlyGetType, it causes its type plus all other types in its defined assembly, to be loaded? And depending on how you loaded the type that will determine if the assembly is loaded reflection only? Why is there no reflection-only flag in the Assembly.Load methods?

Comment: @Mishax Those `GetType` methods will cause the containing assembly to be loaded in the proper context. There are static methods to load an assembly as reflection-only: `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` and `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`.